# Data minimal principle, software architecture

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture

I have a general question and didn't find any information.

I can remember that there is a principle, that you should only pass data,
that is needed for the purpose of the execution.

But i ran into the following Problem with it:

I have multiple Callables in java:

```
public class CallableA implements Callable<Boolean> {
private CallableData data;
public CallableA(CallableData data) {
this.data = data;
    }
}

public class CallableB implements Callable<Boolean> {
private CallableData data;
public CallableB(CallableData data) {
this.data = data;
    }
}

public class CallableC implements Callable<Boolean> {
private CallableData data;
public CallableC(CallableData data) {
this.data = data;
    }
}
```

For my opinion it is better to pass the same class CallableData(as you see above) to all Callables, so i dont need to specify many data classes.
And each Callable uses the data from CallableData it needs.

Or it is recommend to define for every Callable its own Data class
(CallableDataA,CallableDataB,CallableDataC)

But when for example CallableA and CallableB needs the same attribute,
in CallableDataA and CallableDataB is redundant information.

What is the best way to do it ?

Comment: Why *would* you create three classes if they all hold the same data? Seems to me that only 2 classes are needed here.

Comment: If it ends up with `CallableData` having 6 fields and each `Callable` uses 2 different (like `CallabkeA` uses `field1` and `field2`, `CallableB` uses `field3` and `field4` and so on, you'd better create separate classes instead of one.

Comment: Yes lets say CallableData has 6 fields and CallableA uses field1 and field2 CallableB uses field3 and field4 and CallableC uses field5 and field6. But what should i do when there is a 7th field that all Callable Objects uses ?

Comment: @ernest_k because each callable has a different logic, and some attributes from CallableData are shared and some not.

Comment: Fields used by all (or at least several) could be moved to an abstract super class of classes that share that common field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These callable classes have all in common, except the behavior. So the best way is to use abstraction and reuse a superclass among them.

So I'd create an abstract class and make each of these extend it:

```
public abstract class AbstractCallable implements Callable<Boolean> {
    private CallableData data;

    protected AbstractCallable(CallableData data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    protected CallableData getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

That abstract class carries what's common among the callable classes, such that each concrete class will only have the specific implementation of its own `call` logic (all three classes will look similar, but there won't be duplication of code)

Here's one implementation:

```
public class CallableA extends AbstractCallable {
    public CallableA(CallableData data) {
        super(data);
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        CallableData d = this.getData();

        //perform CallableA logic

        return null;
    }
}
```